# Go to Definition of class only showing public members

Tags: c#, visual-studio, metadata, access-modifiers, go-to-definition

When I right click on a class (that is part of an third party assembly - not code I have written) in Visual Studio and select "Go to Definition", I can see all the methods, properties etc of the class.

I notice all these are all `public` and no `private`(or any other level of access) members are shown.

Does this feature only show `public` members of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer on the [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition):

> When you try to run the **Go To Definition** or **Peek Definition** command
>   for types or members that are marked as internal, Visual Studio does
>   not display their metadata as source code, regardless of whether the
>   referencing assembly is a friend or not.

If you want to see the source code of the assembly, you have two options:

- Use a decompile tool like e.g. ILSpy.
- In Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6+, you can set an option to see decompiled source code when you view the definition of a type. This feature can be enabled in the `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced` section.

Comment: Whilst the wording of the document only refers to members being marked as `internal` the decompile tool confirms it is those members marked as `interal` or lower

Comment: Well, `protected` and `private` are either 'internal' from the assembly point of view. That means, they're (normally) not accessible from the outer world. But you're right, they should have stated it more clearly.